# Symfony EventSubscriber using KernelEvents throw me Offset 0 error

Tags: php, symfony

So I'm learning the basis of creating an API.
I'm trying to interact on the creation of a new user by using the API, however I need with symfony to hash passwords.

I made a PasswordEncoderSubscriber method which hash the password before inserting it into the database.

```
private $encoder;

public function __construct(PasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
{
    $this->encoder = $encoder;
}
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        KernelEvents::VIEW => ['encodePassword' => EventPriorities::PRE_WRITE]
    ];
}

public function encodePassword(ViewEvent $event)
{
    $result = $event->getControllerResult();
    $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

    if ($result instanceof User && $method === "POST") {
        $hash = $this->encoder->encodePassword($result, $result->getPassword());
        $result->setPassword($hash);
    }
}
```

I'm using the `KernelEvents::View` to call the function `encodePassword` before it written in the database with `EventPriorities::PRE_WRITE`.

Here's the error I got : **Notice: Undefined offset: 0**.

The code breaks just after the `KernelEvents::VIEW` did I forget something ?

Thanks!

Comment: @u_mulder's answer might get you past this particular issue but using a VIEW event for this sort of thing seems very strange.  Why not encode the password in the same spot where the user is created?  Just inject the encoder.  If you really feel the need for a listener then make your own event and have the controller emit it.  Off-topic but you probably should be using the EncoderFactoryInterface as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62980930/hash-user-password-without-user-instance-in-symfony/62981268#62981268

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [symfony manual](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber) you should provide handler and it's priority as array with 2 items:

```
return [
    KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => [
        ['processException', 10],
    ],
];
```

So, your code should be:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        KernelEvents::VIEW => [
            ['encodePassword', EventPriorities::PRE_WRITE],
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: I've seen the doc and I tried this option, but it seems like by copying and pasting your code makes everything work. Thanks a lot for helping ! (i don't know how to classify this as answered)

Comment: Green tick to accept answer,  uparrow to upvote the answer. Read a [tour] also.