# Why isPasswordValid() function always return false?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, change-password

I am working on a simple reset password system with Symfony4.

I don't know why `isPasswordValid()` always return **false**?

I am using **Bcrypt** to Hash the password
Here is some code of Security.yaml :

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
```

I don't know why `isPasswordValid()` Always returns false.
I manually tried this:

```
$pass="000000000";
dump($encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $pass));
die();
```

and it dump false..

Here is the function I wrote on the controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/password", name="change_pass", methods={"GET","POST"})
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
 */
public function edit(Request $request,UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder): Response
{

    $user = $this->getUser();

    $form = $this->createForm(ResetPassType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $oldPassword = $request->request->get('reset_pass')['oldPassword'];
        $newPassword = $user->getPassword();

        if ($encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $oldPassword)) {
            $hash = $encoder->encodePassword($user,$newPassword);
            $user->setPassword($hash);
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Your password is succesfully changed');
        }else {
            $this->addFlash('fail', 'old password is wrong');
        }

    }
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->refresh($user);

    return $this->render('consultant/changepass.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Here is the form ResetPassType :

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('oldPassword', PasswordType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,])
        ->add('password',PasswordType::class)
        ;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** you are using the new password as the old password's hash.

---

**Explanation:**
I guess you bound your form to your user class.
The `password` field in your form is *mapped*, meaning it updates your user's `password` property.

Therefore, as the property should contain the **hash** of the "old password" but contains your new password, it can't validate.

---

**Solution and improvements:**
The quickest solution would be to *"unmap"* the `password` field or to remove the `data_class` form option, and to replace a line in your controller:

```php
// before: $newPassword = $user->getPassword();
$newPassword = $form->get('password')->getData();
```

I'd suggest to:

- unbind the form to your user class
- use the [UserPassword](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UserPassword.html) validation constraint for your `oldPassword` field
- fetch the form data using `$form->getData()` instead of accessing the `$request` manually

Comment: I read your answer many times
but I am sorry I don't understand it...
I don't understand what I am doing wrong?
Also, I tried using UserPassword validation  as u suggested but it always give a form error even when i write a correct password! and it says that it is wrong
While I am 100% sure of the password!

Comment: @MehDi You bound the form to your User class, didn't you ? I mean: in the `configureOptions()` method, you have set the `data_class` option to your User class. As your form has a `password` field for the new password, it overwrites your property when submitted (it replaces the hash of the old password with the new plain password). It doesn't matter that you enter the correct pass, you replace the hash that you need to validate it with your new password, it can't validate.

Comment: Now I understand what you meant. Yes I see my error was on the `configureOptions()` and the `data_class`  Now I created the form using `createFormBuilder()` instead of using `createForm(ResetPassType)` and the problem is gone! I agree using  **UserPassword** validation is better and easier. Thank you for ur detailed answers/comments.

Comment: @MehDi glad you understood it. By the way, it's better to use `createForm()` with a separate form class than building your form directly in your controller (your controller should not have to worry about the form details).

Comment: Bit off-topic but I find that UserPasswordEncoder to bit difficult to reason about.  It hides some of what is going on leading to issues such as your question.  Consider using the [EncoderFactoryInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62980930/hash-user-password-without-user-instance-in-symfony/62981268#62981268) .  It may make your code a bit easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You will change your form because if you keep the field password, the password of the user will be changed by form too, so the right way is  :

-in your Form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('oldPassword', PasswordType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,])
        ->add('newPassword',PasswordType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,])
        ;
    }
```

and then in your controller change the way you get the new password

```
$oldPassword = $request->request->get('reset_pass')['oldPassword'];
$newPassword = $request->request->get('reset_pass')['newPassword'];
```

Have fun :)