# symfony + phpunit - how to test UserFactory with PasswordEncoder dependencies

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, factory

Hello i have problem with my test.
I'm trying to test UserFactory which is creating UserObject by UserDto data.
I dont know how to test it because factory need PasswordEncoder in dependencies.

```
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Service\Factory\UserFactory;
use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject as MockObject;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class UserFactoryTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @covers UserFactory
     */
    public function testShouldCreateUserObjectFromUserDto()
    {
        //Given
        /**
         * @var UserDto | MockObject
         */
        $userDto = $this->getMockBuilder(UserDto::class);

        //When
        $userFactory = new UserFactory(/* PASSWORD ENCODER */);
        $user = $userFactory->create($userDto);

        //Then
        $this->assertInstanceOf(User::class, $user);
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Service\Factory;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class UserFactory
{
    /**
     * @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface
     */
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public function create(UserDto $dto)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setPassword($this->encoder->encodePassword($dto->plainPassword));
        /**
         * CODE..
         */
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Is this right? how can i test this factory which have dependencies?
i cant user __construct in my TestClass

Comment: In case you are wondering, the first argument to your user encoder must be an instance of User.  The encoder only uses it to get the user class so it does not matter what is actually in it.  Might be cleaner to use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62980930/hash-user-password-without-user-instance-in-symfony/62981268#62981268 but the results will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

(Hint: apparently you're using the UserPasswordEncoderInterface wrong, because it's not a PasswordEncoderInterface - the former additionally expects the User as a param, while the latter does not, which I just learned today, you might want to fix that)

In general, you have to provide all dependencies for the class to be tested. There are different approaches, essentially: Implementing a reduced version of the interface (if it's an interface), actually finding the dependency and instantiate it or use a mock and tell it what will happen to it. The latter can be done if you generally know what happens with the dependency (non-blackbox testing).

So, you could just mock the interface with some well defined behavior:

```
//$upe = $this->getMockBuilder(\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface::class)->getMock();
$upe = $this->getMockBuilder(\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface::class)->getMock();
$upe->expects($this->any())
            ->method('encodePassword')
            // omit following line, if you don't want to check for param
            ->with($this->equalTo('plainPassword')) 
            ->willReturn('encodedPassword');
```

and then provide that mock to your userfactory:

```
$userfactory = new UserFactory($upe);
```

this is somewhat dependant on the implementation of UserFactory though, expecting it to essentially be called in the specified way and which will return the same string always. (You can go deeper into mocking and/or implement the interface yourself to have more control)

Comment: You need to mock the EncoderFactory and then have it return a mocked PasswordEncoder.  Kind of a pain no matter how you do it.

Comment: @Cerad: are you sure? don't see any factory being used to request the encoder, encodePassword is being called on the mock *should* work fine?

Comment: It's works i guess. Thank you i will remember this solution anyway i have another problem.

This line:         $user = $userFactory->create($userDto);
create method need UserDto Class but my mock is making MockClass and i got this problem

Argument 1 passed to App\Service\Factory\UserFactory::create() must be an instance of App\Service\Factory\UserDto, instance of Mock_UserDto_b5c48bbf given

How can i solve this?

Comment: i forgot to add how i do this mock:         $userDto = $this->getMockBuilder(UserDto::class)->getMock();

Comment: @Jakumi UserPasswordEncoderInterface (form the original question) uses the EncoderFactory to get a specific PasswordEncoder for a given User class.  At a minimum your mock code needs to check that two arguments are passed to encodePassword.  The first one being a user object.  But I think I am just confusing the issue here and will bow out.

Comment: @Raptor2 do you have the correct UserDto *use clause* at the top of the file? otherwise the namespace is used you got.

Comment: yes, that was the problem i didnt figure it out.
Storm is so stupid sometimes