# Cannot autowire PasswordHasherInterface

Tags: php, symfony, hash, frameworks, passwords

I'm trying to autowire PasswordHasherInterface in the Fixtures class:

```
<?php
namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Model\User\Entity\User\Email;
use App\Model\User\Entity\User\Id;
use App\Model\User\Entity\User\Role;
use App\Model\User\Entity\User\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\PasswordHasherInterface;

class UserFixture extends Fixture
{
    private PasswordHasherInterface $hasher;

    public function __construct(PasswordHasherInterface $hasher)
    {
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
    }
    
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        $hash = $this->hasher->hash("password");

        $user = User::signUpByEmail(
            Id::next(),
            new \DateTimeImmutable(),
            new Email("admin@app.test"),
            $hash,
            "token"
        );

        $user->confirmSignUp();

        $user->changeRole(Role::admin());

        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

But I got error:

In DefinitionErrorExceptionPass.php line 54:
!!
!!    Cannot autowire service "App\DataFixtures\UserFixture": argument "$hasher"
!!    of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Component\PasswordH
!!    asher\PasswordHasherInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a
!!    class that implements this interface?
!!

My file services.yaml:

```
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Model/User/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
```

How to hash plain password in Symfony 6.1?
Why I get this error?

Comment: Could you post your file system structure? It appears you're missing a service/class that implements `Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\PasswordHasherInterface`

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62980930/hash-user-password-without-user-instance-in-symfony/62981268#62981268 except that for S5 and later you use the PasswordHasherFactoryInterface instead of EncoderFactoryInterface.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general `PasswordHasher`.

Either you:

- generate a specific one using a factory: e.g. `Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\PasswordHasherFactoryInterface`
- or you use a dedicated password hasher class: e.g. `Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface` for users*.

Using a factory, your code would look like this: (untested)

```
//...
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\PasswordHasherFactoryInterface;


class UserFixture extends Fixture
{
    private PasswordHasherFactoryInterface $passwordHasherFactory;

    public function __construct(PasswordHasherFactoryInterface $hasherFactory)
    {
      $this->passwordHasherFactory = $passwordHasherFactory;
    }
    
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        $passwordHasher = $this->passwordHasherFactory->getPasswordHasher(User::class);
        $hash = $passwordHasher->hash("password");

        $user = User::signUpByEmail(
            Id::next(),
            new \DateTimeImmutable(),
            new Email("admin@app.test"),
            $hash,
            "token"
        );

        $user->confirmSignUp();

        $user->changeRole(Role::admin());

        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();
    }
```

Just to reiterate, the steps are:

1. Install the package: `composer require symfony/password-hasher`
2. [Configure the hasher](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/passwords.html#configuring-a-password-hasher)
3. Load a hasher

   - Load the `UserPasswordHasherInterface` OR
   - Load the `PasswordHasherFactoryInterface` (see [example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/passwords.html#hashing-the-password)) and get the `PasswordHasher`

*: An example of `UserPasswordHasherInterface` for a fixure is located [here](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/current/index.html#accessing-services-from-the-fixtures).

Comment: @Cerad  Yes, it was fun :) As you might guess, I'm not too experienced with Symfony. Is there a quick way to set up a dev environment to test code in this question?